# How does an anchor tag work that does not specify a filename?

Tags: html

How does an anchor tag work that does not specify a filename?
Example: 
    `<a href="/fastcars">Fast Cars</a>`

I was under the impression the HTML file had to be expressly cited, but in this case it is not, just the directory name.

Does this reference an HTML file, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the webserver configuration, pointing to a directory might mean pointing to the index file of that folder, or even at whatever other file you want to rewrite.

There was a time in which SEO practices reccomended using folder style permalinks instead of query strings. So there were cases in which

```
/index.php?section=fastcars
```

was rewritten as

```
/fastcars
```

Again, this is all rewrite magic. Most webservers offer some kind of rewrite rules to achieve this.

Besides, an `a` element doesn't need to point to a file or url address. They can be used as internal navigation links to point to an anchor, and JS frameworks such as jQuery have popularized its use only as button replacements to trigger a given behavior.

Answer (score 0):

An anchor tag's `href` attribute does not reference a *file*; it references a URL. What that URI corresponds to is completely opaque. In the most common case where the URL uses the HTTP(S) protocol, that URL is sent to the server as part of a request.

It's the server, and only the server, that determines what the URL corresponds to. It doesn't have to be a file or anything else that you might consider tangible, and you can't tell looking at it from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The main function of the "a" attribute is to create links. That means a link to an external website:

```
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
```

or a link within the same page. Just create an id - for example:

```
<h2 id="top">text text text</h2>
```

then create a link using that id -

```
<a href="#top">Top</a>
```

Every time you click on the link, your browser will send you to the part of the page where your id is.